# MariaDB JSON_ARRAY_APPEND Object instead of it's string representation

Tags: arrays, json, mariadb

I am receiving quoted string values in an array instead of an array of objects when I use JSON_ARRAY_APPEND() to insert a string that represents an object.

I need a way to force the value inserted to the array to be the object instead of it's string representation.

Server:
10.2.18-MariaDB-log
MariaDB Server
Linux x86_64

Here is a sample I am trying to get work:

```
set @NewArrayItem = '{"item2": "value2"}';
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('{"SomeData": "SomeValue", "AnArray": [{"item1": "value1"}]}', '$.AnArray', @NewArrayItem ) as outval;
```

The second element in the array ($.AnArray[1]) is a string instead of an object.

I am expecting:

```
{"SomeData": "SomeValue", "AnArray": [{"item1": "value1"}, {"item2": "value2"}]}
```

But I actually get:

```
{"SomeData": "SomeValue", "AnArray": [{"item1": "value1"}, "{\"item2\": \"value2\"}"]}
```

I see that the following works, but my constraint is that value @NewArrayItem is a properly formatted string from another application:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('{"SomeData": "SomeValue", "AnArray": [{"item1": "value1"}]}', '$.AnArray', JSON_OBJECT('item2','value2') ) as outval;
```

Comment: Might it be better to use actual columns instead of hiding data in JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a combination of JSON_SET, JSON_MERGE, and JSON_QUERY:

```
set @ExistingData = '{"SomeData": "SomeValue", "AnArray": [{"item1": "value1"}]}';
set @NewArrayItem = '{"item2": "value2"}';
SELECT JSON_SET(@ExistingData, '$.AnArray', JSON_MERGE(ifnull(JSON_QUERY(@ExistingData, '$.AnArray'),'[]'),@NewArrayItem) ) as outval;
```

As a bonus, it also works for the case where the array does not exist:

```
set @ExistingData = '{"SomeData": "SomeValue"}';
set @NewArrayItem = '{"item2": "value2"}';
SELECT JSON_SET(@ExistingData, '$.AnArray', JSON_MERGE(ifnull(JSON_QUERY(@ExistingData, '$.AnArray'),'[]'),@NewArrayItem) ) as outval;
```

Still looking for a more simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

I try this example

```
SET @json = '[]';
SELECT @json; // []
SET @json = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@json, '$', JSON_OBJECT("id", 1, "name", "Month1"));
SELECT @json; // [{"id": 1, "name": "Month1"}]
SET @json = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@json, '$', JSON_OBJECT("id", 2, "name", "Month2"));
SELECT @json; // [{"id": 1, "name": "Month1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Month2"}]
```